# testng suite doesn't run in the order specified

Tags: java, testng

I have below testng test suite.

```
<suite name="MySuite" parallel="false">
    <test name="MyTest" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test1"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test2"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test3"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test4"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test5"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test6"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test7"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test8"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test9"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test10"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test11"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test12"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test13"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test14"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test15"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test16"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test17"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test18"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test19"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test20"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test21"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test22"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test23"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test24"/>
            <class name="com.my.package.Test25"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I use testng 6.14.3

And I execute the suite with following command.

```
mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=suite.xml
```

I expect the tests to run in the order specified in the xml (I have used `preserve-order="true"` attribute). But, the tests are executed in below order.

```
com.my.package.Test1
com.my.package.Test23
com.my.package.Test2
com.my.package.Test24
com.my.package.Test3
com.my.package.Test25
com.my.package.Test4
com.my.package.Test5
com.my.package.Test6
...
...
```

If the number of test classes is less than 23, they run in the given order. But, when the count is 23 or more, tests are executed in above pattern.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Can you please tell us more on what your test classes look like (I mean all of 24 odd test classes). If they all look the same, it would be great if you could please edit your question and show the sample of one of them. If they are all different, we would need to atleast see a trimmed down version of them.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan Thanks for pointing out that there may be something wrong with a test. The cause was not having any test methods in `Test22`

Comment: Does it mean that the test class `Test22` had anything else (such as TestNG configuration methods etc.,) or was it just an empty class with all of its code commented out. Just trying to figure out if this is a bug in TestNG that I should go back to fixing.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan it had a `@BeforeMethod` method. The actual test was commented out.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The cause was class `Test22` not having any test methods in it. The test that was there had been commented out. When the test was added again to the class, suite started to run again in expected order.

Not sure whether this is a bug in Testng or not.